# File upload not hitting controller before upload is finished and temporarily saved to disk

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, fluentftp

Let's imagine I am running a .NET Core API on a device with 1GB storage and 1GB RAM. I want to upload a file from my website directly to a FTP server, without the file getting cached in memory or on disk. I have this working for downloading files, as I basically act as a proxy, by opening the FTP file in a stream, then streaming that directly to the `HttpContext.Request.Body`.

For uploading, I want to hit the controller immediately. I can see it caches to disk now, and that's probably because of my `EnableBuffering` attribute. I have a regular `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` that POSTs to my .NET Core backend. The controller looks like this:

```
[EnableBuffering]
[RequestFormLimits(ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue, MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue)]
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(string path)
{
    if (!IsMultipartContentType(HttpContext.Request.ContentType))
        return BadRequest("Not multipart request");

    await _fileProvider.Upload(path);

    return Ok();
}
```

EnableBuffering:

```
public class EnableBufferingAttribute : Attribute, IResourceFilter
{
    public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();
    }

    public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context) {}
}
```

Upload logic:

```
public async Task Upload(string path)
{
    const int buffer = 8 * 1024;

    var request = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;
    var boundary = request.GetMultipartBoundary();
    var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, request.Body, buffer);
    var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();

    using (var client = await _ftpHelper.GetFtpClient())
    {
        while (section != null)
        {
            var fileSection = section.AsFileSection();

            if (fileSection != null)
            {
                var fileName = fileSection.FileName;

                var uploadPath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);

                var stream = await client.OpenWriteAsync(uploadPath);
                await section.Body.CopyToAsync(stream, buffer);
            }

            section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

If I don't enable buffering, I get:

> System.IO.IOException: Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component.

However, by enabling buffering, I can see it says:

> Ensure the requestBody can be read multiple times. Normally buffers request bodies in memory; **writes requests larger than 30K bytes to disk**.

So that part makes sense. However, how do I get around this problem? If I set a breakpoint on the first line of the `Upload()` method, and then start an upload, it uploads the file first **AND THEN** hits the breakpoint.

Can I get around this so it hits my controller immediately and starts uploading to the FTP server, without saving to disk first?

Comment: Try using log output instead of setting a breakpoint, as it may interfere with upload workflow

Comment: @HirasawaYui I can guarantee it does not hit the controller before upload is finished. Tested by building and deploying to a production environment.

Comment: You will need buffering, but just use a small buffer.
The default buffersize used in CopyTo is 82kb, which means that you can transfer huge files while only using 82kb of memory per transfer

Comment: @MalteR Yep, that is correct, however, that won't solve my issue with files being cached on disk. Even if I remove the EnableBuffering attribute, it still uploads the files first while saving to disk temporarily, and then it hits my controller.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why request is processed prior entering the `Upload` method is the [Form model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding#sources).
`Upload` method has `path` parameter and it value comes from the form data. As result, the request need to be parsed prior calling controller method to extract `path` parameter value from form data.
Also in this case, the list and content of uploaded files can be retrieved using [`Files`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformcollection.files) collection available via `HttpContext` property of the `ControllerBase` class.

```
this.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files
```

The easiest way to workaround this behavior is to disable form model binding and pass the `path` parameter via the query string.

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
[DisableFormValueModelBinding]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload([FromQuery] string path)
```

The source code of `DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute` can be found in [Upload files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads#upload-large-files-with-streaming) article.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute : Attribute, IResourceFilter
{
    public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
    {
        var factories = context.ValueProviderFactories;
        factories.RemoveType<FormValueProviderFactory>();
        factories.RemoveType<FormFileValueProviderFactory>();
        factories.RemoveType<JQueryFormValueProviderFactory>();
    }

    public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```